# Firestore query in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to improve my Firestore query, but I got an error.
I have simple Firestore db: collection 'Spanish' where each collection has only one document 'words'.
The original working code code is:

```
var myData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Spanish')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) {
    if (snapshot != null) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        element.data().forEach((key, value) {
          myMap.putIfAbsent(key, () => value);
          myDictionary.add(key + '@' + value);
        });
      });
```

Since the collection has only one document I tried to improve the query by getting all fields from the selected document, so my new query is:

```
var myData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Spanish').doc('words')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) {
    if (snapshot != null) {
      snapshot.data().forEach((key, value) {
          myMap.putIfAbsent(key, () => value);
          myDictionary.add(key + '@' + value);
        });
```

Now I am getting error on forEach, which says:

> "The method 'forEach' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
>
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target"

But I am checking for null in "if (snapshot != null)"
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

That is because `data()` could return `null`. Add a null-check operator or a bang operator there.

```dart
snapshot.data()?.forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

from the official [documentation of the firebase firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#documentsnapshot)

> A DocumentSnapshot is returned from a query, or by accessing the document directly. Even if no document exists in the database, a snapshot will always be returned.

so actually using `if (snapshot != null)` doesn't do anything since it will never be null

when you call the `data()` on the `snapshot`, you got a `Map<String, dynamic>` and what exactly could be `null`, since it will be coming from a firebase request, dart doesn't know if it's null or not, so you need to take a null safety action over it.

since you said that the collection has that **words** for sure, then you could tell dart this with `!` :

```
snapshot!.data()!
```

or if you're not sure that is null or not use a `?`, then handle it with a `if else` :

```
if(snapshot?.data()? == null) {
  /* action */
  }  else {
  /* action */  
  }
```